# How to make non-editable element in a container with contentEditable?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I'm trying to make an editor that inserts special types of elements. I figured out that if you set contenteditable to false on the elements within it, it wont let you type inside it (which is good), but it doesn't put the cursor before or after either, the cursor just disappears.

Is there a way to stop the user from typing inside the element but retain cursor focus when you click on it, as if it's a normal text symbol?

```css
div div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

div {background: #ccc}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
this one will let you type<div></div>inside the red box
</div>

<div contenteditable="true">
this one wont, <div contenteditable="false"></div> but the cursor does nothing when you click inside it now
</div>


<div contenteditable="true">
cant place cursor after this box <div contenteditable="false"></div>
</div>
```

You also cant click at the end of the text block if the block is last.

Big problem for usability, really would like to fix this.

Facebook has solved this problem, but I can't figure out if it's with js or css:

[image]

edit: I've discovered fb changes the caret-color property to black, but it then seems to jump to the position outside of the span after you type, which must be done with js. Still trying to figure out how.

edit: Tried a lot of things, thought I had it working but it still caused other weird problems. I recommend you just don't attempt this and just use an image element or emoji.

Comment: Use java script on change event to disable the editable when contenteditable="false"

Comment: that just adds contenteditable="false" to them which they already have

Comment: @stackers so you want to put the cursor _after_ the red box upon clicking the red box itself?

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 before or after, yes. clicking anywhere inside the div should put a cursor somewhere, I just want it to be before or after my element, not inside it.

Comment: Having struggled with this issue before, I can tell you that inserting a zero-width white-space will prevent the element from swallowing up the cursor. However, if you want any sort of advanced functionality, you might want to look into prebuilt contenteditable libraries, which are all designed to handle cases like this, due to inconsistent contenteditable implementation: such as ProseMirror or Quill.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `readonly` attribute is the tool for the job and has acceptable support [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-read-only-write).

```
[contenteditable]:read-only {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/read-write-read/) article is legit.

Comment: I would use the `not-allowed` cursor for the disabled state. read-only should use the `text` cursor to indicate ability to copy text IMO.